# How to re-open in-app pop-up windows from command line?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a windows app that contain (within itself) a number of windows. One of these is an alert pop-up window that can be programmed (within the app) to pop-up under certain conditions. However, once it is closed there is no functionality (within the main app) to make it comeback, even though all the information is still in it, next time it pops up.

I'm not sure this is possible, but at some place it was suggested to look at [ShowWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function, or at the [WAD](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver) (*Windows Application Driver*) framework. However, I have no idea how to use and compile this stuff, so something useful from the Powershell command line would be great.

**How can I find and re-open a closed sub-window from a windows app, using Powershell or CLI magic?**

---

Possibly [Related](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/windows):
* `ShowOwnedPopups` - Shows or hides all pop-up windows owned by the specified window.
* `ShowWindow` - Sets the specified window's show state.
* `ShowWindowAsync` - Sets the show state of a window created by a different thread.

Comment: As @harrymc points out below.  You are not likely to solve this.  It is possible that the window still exists as a hidden window (howbeit unlikely).  If this were true, you could find the window (through code) and make it visible (also through code).  The API's to research would be FindWindow() and ShowWindow().  This is not trivial for someone not versed in the win32 api and probably wouldn't be fruitful even if it were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a window is closed, it cannot be reopened, except by its application.

If the application is not programmed for it, your only option is to take a
screenshot of the window, if you wish to later consult this information.

If you would like to track the window to see if it still exists,
you may use [SpyPlusPlus](https://github.com/westoncampbell/SpyPlusPlus).

Comment: True.. but he said ***"even though all the information is still in it, next time it pops up"***.. it is *POSSIBLE* that the window wasn't destroyed.  Only hidden.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: No reason that the application will forget its data. However, I added a utility for tracking the window, to see if it still exists, if the poster would like to follow your comment.

Comment: Any idea how to use the *SpyPluPlus* tool? There's no documentation at all...

Comment: The documentation is included in the form of a `.chm` file, also accessible from the menu *Help > Help Topics*.

Comment: Would have been nice to revive and update that. Where are the sources?

Comment: The download contains proprietary software by Microsoft, so no sources. This software is still available as part of Visual Studio under the name of `Spy++`. There are third-party similar products, but this one is the best.